# How does WideCharToMultiByte deal with codepages?

Tags: unicode, encoding, character-encoding

When I execute the below code, why am I getting `'?'` for the first case? AFAIK, codepage 932 supports line draw characters.

How does this API deal with codepages? AFAIK, it searches and maps the character in the codepage, then returns the position of the character from the codepage.

```
typedef struct dbcs {
    unsigned char HighByte;
    unsigned char LowByte;
} DBCS;

static DBCS set[5] = {0x25,0x5D};
unsigned char array[2];

#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    // printf("hello world");
    int str_size;
    LPCWSTR                 charpntr;
    LPSTR                   getcd;
    LPBOOL                  flg;
    int i ;

    array[0] = set[0].LowByte;
    array[1] = set[0].HighByte;
    charpntr = &array;
    str_size = WideCharToMultiByte(932, 0, charpntr, 1, getcd, 2, NULL, NULL);
    printf(" value of %u", getcd);
    printf("number of bytes %d character is  %s", str_size, getcd);
    printf("\n");

    array[0] = set[0].LowByte;
    array[1] = set[0].HighByte;
    charpntr = &array;
    str_size = WideCharToMultiByte(437, 0, charpntr, 1, getcd, 2, NULL, NULL);
    printf(" value of %u", getcd);
    printf("number of bytes %d character is  %s", str_size, getcd);
    printf("\n");
}
```

Result of execution in CodeBlocks:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Windows codepage 932 is not a simple thing - as it uses multibyte characters.

I have no Windows here, so I have been experimenting with the encoding of the character you are using in Python3, in an UTF-8 terminal: it works fine with cp437 and UTF-8, but Python refuses to encode the character to what it calls "cp932", or any of its aliases listed in the Wikipedia article:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_page_932_(Microsoft_Windows)

It may be a fault in Python's internal Unicode tables (fetched directly from the Unicode consortium), or possibly, this codepage don't map this character at all.

Anyway, there are problems in your code: one is that you never initialize `getcd`. Reading the docs for `WideCharToMultiByte()`, one see it should not be set to NULL, so you have to have the proper return buffer allocated there.

So, try putting the `getcd` declaration as:

char                   getcd[6]={};

That should give you enough space for even the widest characters you experiment with, and include a string `\x00` terminator.

And another thing is that if these line drawing characters are present in CP932, they are definitely multibyte - thus the `cbMultiByte` parameter for the call (the "1" after `charptr`) should be set to at least 2. If no other error kicks in, and the char exists in cp932, this alone might fix your issue.

Comment: It shouldn't be `LPSTR getcd[]`, it should be `char getcd[]`. An empty initializer will zero fill, so the simplest would be `char getcd[6]={}`.